# Extra class prediction result shown when testing on AlexeyAB Yolov4 Darknet package on Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, object-detection, darknet, yolov4

I have done the model training for Yolov4 objection detection from AlexeyAB Darknet package on Colab.
(from https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet)
Two classes are defined named "scratch" and "blood".
Then run the following commands for testing on a single image:

!./darknet detector test data/obj.data cfg/yolo-obj.cfg backup/yolo-object_last.weights images/meat/test/376.jpg -dont show

and the result is shown below. It's expected that there are only one scratch and blood shown with probabilities in the result.
However, it shows so many scratch and blood predictions (the last few lines of this post)!
The number of classes (=2), class names, and shoud have been set properly in obj.data and yolo-obj.cfg.
Can anyone advice why and how to resolve it?

```
 CUDA-version: 11010 (11020), cuDNN: 7.6.5, GPU count: 1  
 OpenCV version: 3.2.0
 0 : compute_capability = 370, cudnn_half = 0, GPU: Tesla K80 
net.optimized_memory = 0 
mini_batch = 1, batch = 1, time_steps = 1, train = 0 
   layer   filters  size/strd(dil)      input                output
   0 Create CUDA-stream - 0 
 Create cudnn-handle 0 
conv     32       3 x 3/ 1    416 x 416 x   3 ->  416 x 416 x  32 0.299 BF
   1 conv     64       3 x 3/ 2    416 x 416 x  32 ->  208 x 208 x  64 1.595 BF
   2 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    208 x 208 x  64 ->  208 x 208 x  64 0.354 BF
   3 route  1                                  ->  208 x 208 x  64 
   4 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    208 x 208 x  64 ->  208 x 208 x  64 0.354 BF
   5 conv     32       1 x 1/ 1    208 x 208 x  64 ->  208 x 208 x  32 0.177 BF
   6 conv     64       3 x 3/ 1    208 x 208 x  32 ->  208 x 208 x  64 1.595 BF
   7 Shortcut Layer: 4,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs: 208 x 208 x  64 0.003 BF
   8 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    208 x 208 x  64 ->  208 x 208 x  64 0.354 BF
   9 route  8 2                                ->  208 x 208 x 128 
  10 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    208 x 208 x 128 ->  208 x 208 x  64 0.709 BF
  11 conv    128       3 x 3/ 2    208 x 208 x  64 ->  104 x 104 x 128 1.595 BF
  12 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    104 x 104 x 128 ->  104 x 104 x  64 0.177 BF
  13 route  11                                 ->  104 x 104 x 128 
  14 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    104 x 104 x 128 ->  104 x 104 x  64 0.177 BF
  15 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    104 x 104 x  64 ->  104 x 104 x  64 0.089 BF
  16 conv     64       3 x 3/ 1    104 x 104 x  64 ->  104 x 104 x  64 0.797 BF
  17 Shortcut Layer: 14,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs: 104 x 104 x  64 0.001 BF
  18 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    104 x 104 x  64 ->  104 x 104 x  64 0.089 BF
  19 conv     64       3 x 3/ 1    104 x 104 x  64 ->  104 x 104 x  64 0.797 BF
  20 Shortcut Layer: 17,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs: 104 x 104 x  64 0.001 BF
  21 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    104 x 104 x  64 ->  104 x 104 x  64 0.089 BF
  22 route  21 12                              ->  104 x 104 x 128 
  23 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1    104 x 104 x 128 ->  104 x 104 x 128 0.354 BF
  24 conv    256       3 x 3/ 2    104 x 104 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 256 1.595 BF
  25 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 256 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.177 BF
  26 route  24                                 ->   52 x  52 x 256 
  27 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 256 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.177 BF
  28 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.089 BF
  29 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.797 BF
  30 Shortcut Layer: 27,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  52 x  52 x 128 0.000 BF
  31 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.089 BF
  32 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.797 BF
  33 Shortcut Layer: 30,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  52 x  52 x 128 0.000 BF
  34 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.089 BF
  35 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.797 BF
  36 Shortcut Layer: 33,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  52 x  52 x 128 0.000 BF
  37 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.089 BF
  38 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.797 BF
  39 Shortcut Layer: 36,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  52 x  52 x 128 0.000 BF
  40 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.089 BF
  41 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.797 BF
  42 Shortcut Layer: 39,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  52 x  52 x 128 0.000 BF
  43 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.089 BF
  44 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.797 BF
  45 Shortcut Layer: 42,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  52 x  52 x 128 0.000 BF
  46 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.089 BF
  47 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.797 BF
  48 Shortcut Layer: 45,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  52 x  52 x 128 0.000 BF
  49 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.089 BF
  50 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.797 BF
  51 Shortcut Layer: 48,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  52 x  52 x 128 0.000 BF
  52 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.089 BF
  53 route  52 25                              ->   52 x  52 x 256 
  54 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 256 ->   52 x  52 x 256 0.354 BF
  55 conv    512       3 x 3/ 2     52 x  52 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 512 1.595 BF
  56 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.177 BF
  57 route  55                                 ->   26 x  26 x 512 
  58 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.177 BF
  59 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.089 BF
  60 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.797 BF
  61 Shortcut Layer: 58,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  26 x  26 x 256 0.000 BF
  62 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.089 BF
  63 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.797 BF
  64 Shortcut Layer: 61,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  26 x  26 x 256 0.000 BF
  65 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.089 BF
  66 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.797 BF
  67 Shortcut Layer: 64,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  26 x  26 x 256 0.000 BF
  68 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.089 BF
  69 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.797 BF
  70 Shortcut Layer: 67,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  26 x  26 x 256 0.000 BF
  71 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.089 BF
  72 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.797 BF
  73 Shortcut Layer: 70,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  26 x  26 x 256 0.000 BF
  74 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.089 BF
  75 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.797 BF
  76 Shortcut Layer: 73,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  26 x  26 x 256 0.000 BF
  77 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.089 BF
  78 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.797 BF
  79 Shortcut Layer: 76,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  26 x  26 x 256 0.000 BF
  80 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.089 BF
  81 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.797 BF
  82 Shortcut Layer: 79,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  26 x  26 x 256 0.000 BF
  83 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.089 BF
  84 route  83 56                              ->   26 x  26 x 512 
  85 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 512 0.354 BF
  86 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 2     26 x  26 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x1024 1.595 BF
  87 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x1024 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.177 BF
  88 route  86                                 ->   13 x  13 x1024 
  89 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x1024 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.177 BF
  90 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.089 BF
  91 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.797 BF
  92 Shortcut Layer: 89,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  13 x  13 x 512 0.000 BF
  93 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.089 BF
  94 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.797 BF
  95 Shortcut Layer: 92,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  13 x  13 x 512 0.000 BF
  96 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.089 BF
  97 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.797 BF
  98 Shortcut Layer: 95,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  13 x  13 x 512 0.000 BF
  99 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.089 BF
 100 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.797 BF
 101 Shortcut Layer: 98,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  13 x  13 x 512 0.000 BF
 102 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.089 BF
 103 route  102 87                             ->   13 x  13 x1024 
 104 conv   1024       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x1024 ->   13 x  13 x1024 0.354 BF
 105 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x1024 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.177 BF
 106 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x1024 1.595 BF
 107 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x1024 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.177 BF
 108 max                5x 5/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.002 BF
 109 route  107                                    ->   13 x  13 x 512 
 110 max                9x 9/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.007 BF
 111 route  107                                    ->   13 x  13 x 512 
 112 max               13x13/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.015 BF
 113 route  112 110 108 107                        ->   13 x  13 x2048 
 114 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x2048 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.354 BF
 115 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x1024 1.595 BF
 116 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x1024 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.177 BF
 117 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 256 0.044 BF
 118 upsample                 2x    13 x  13 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256
 119 route  85                                 ->   26 x  26 x 512 
 120 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.177 BF
 121 route  120 118                                ->   26 x  26 x 512 
 122 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.177 BF
 123 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 512 1.595 BF
 124 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.177 BF
 125 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 512 1.595 BF
 126 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.177 BF
 127 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 128 0.044 BF
 128 upsample                 2x    26 x  26 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128
 129 route  54                                 ->   52 x  52 x 256 
 130 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 256 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.177 BF
 131 route  130 128                                ->   52 x  52 x 256 
 132 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 256 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.177 BF
 133 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 256 1.595 BF
 134 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 256 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.177 BF
 135 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 256 1.595 BF
 136 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 256 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.177 BF
 137 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 256 1.595 BF
 138 conv     21       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 256 ->   52 x  52 x  21 0.029 BF
 139 yolo
[yolo] params: iou loss: ciou (4), iou_norm: 0.07, obj_norm: 1.00, cls_norm: 1.00, delta_norm: 1.00, scale_x_y: 1.20
nms_kind: greedynms (1), beta = 0.600000 
 140 route  136                                    ->   52 x  52 x 128 
 141 conv    256       3 x 3/ 2     52 x  52 x 128 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.399 BF
 142 route  141 126                                ->   26 x  26 x 512 
 143 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.177 BF
 144 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 512 1.595 BF
 145 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.177 BF
 146 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 512 1.595 BF
 147 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.177 BF
 148 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 512 1.595 BF
 149 conv     21       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 512 ->   26 x  26 x  21 0.015 BF
 150 yolo
[yolo] params: iou loss: ciou (4), iou_norm: 0.07, obj_norm: 1.00, cls_norm: 1.00, delta_norm: 1.00, scale_x_y: 1.10
nms_kind: greedynms (1), beta = 0.600000 
 151 route  147                                    ->   26 x  26 x 256 
 152 conv    512       3 x 3/ 2     26 x  26 x 256 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.399 BF
 153 route  152 116                                ->   13 x  13 x1024 
 154 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x1024 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.177 BF
 155 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x1024 1.595 BF
 156 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x1024 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.177 BF
 157 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x1024 1.595 BF
 158 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x1024 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.177 BF
 159 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x1024 1.595 BF
 160 conv     21       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x1024 ->   13 x  13 x  21 0.007 BF
 161 yolo
[yolo] params: iou loss: ciou (4), iou_norm: 0.07, obj_norm: 1.00, cls_norm: 1.00, delta_norm: 1.00, scale_x_y: 1.05
nms_kind: greedynms (1), beta = 0.600000 
Total BFLOPS 59.570 
avg_outputs = 489910 
 Allocate additional workspace_size = 12.46 MB 
Loading weights from backup/yolo-object_last.weights...
 seen 64, trained: 57 K-images (0 Kilo-batches_64) 
Done! Loaded 160 layers from weights-file 
 Detection layer: 139 - type = 28 
 Detection layer: 150 - type = 28 
 Detection layer: 161 - type = 28 
images/meat/13.jpg: Predicted in 101.928000 milli-seconds.
scratch: 52%
blood: 36%
scratch: 68%
blood: 68%
scratch: 42%
blood: 42%
scratch: 60%
blood: 60%
scratch: 43%
blood: 43%
scratch: 45%
blood: 45%
blood: 48%
scratch: 42%
scratch: 45%
blood: 45%
scratch: 65%
blood: 65%
scratch: 56%
```

.....(much more scratch and blood shown below....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behaviour.

You are "always" going to get a lot of detections. But you can also see that some of your detections are below the 50% confidence score. Which should be discarded.

I think the pipeline already performs Non-maximum suppression (NMS) to remove duplicates and overlapping detections (not sure), but you can additionally set up confidence score threshold as well, to show only above 50% with `-thresh 0.5`

This will give you final expected results. Still, if you continue to obtain more than you should, well, this is the goal of everyone :)

It's all about hyperparameter tuning and more data to train our models to give our desired outcome.

Comment: There is only one object on the image. I guess it's because there is problem on the trained model then cause lots of bounding boxes detected by the model. Will need to check why the model is not accurate. Thanks for the answer and it helps!

Comment: @weiming did you solve the problem? Could you help me in multiple detection, please?